# How can I add to a variable with a textbox and button?

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to make an application that can add and subtract from a variable using buttons and a textbox. I got the buttons working correctly, but when it comes to adding to the variable using the textbox I have a bit of trouble. I am trying to make it so the user can enter a number into the text area, press a button and have it add to the total number.

However, when I enter in a number (say I start at 5,000) and press the button it will give me 5000.02131427474

No matter what I put in it will always give me those decimals back. Are there any ways to fix this? Any help would be appreciated.

this is the code for the addition button I am having trouble with

```
    //Add LP by entered number
    Button btnAdd = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnAdd);

    btnAdd.setOnClickListener( new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Lp1 = Double.parseDouble(Lp1 + (String.valueOf(enterLp)));
            txtLp1.setText(String.valueOf(Lp1));
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can parse the value as an int..Integer.parseInt()

Comment: This won't work if number in textview has a decimal point(eg. 5.3).

Answer (score 0):

Use Float instead of Double. `Lp1 += Float.parseFloat(String.valueOf(enterLp));`